# React Context in NextJs 13.2

Tags: next.js, react-context

Im trying to use React context in NextJs 13, i faced an error
[image]

This is my context -

```
'use client';
import { MutableRefObject, createContext, useRef, useContext } from "react";

interface ContextProviderProps{
    children: React.ReactNode;
  }

const GlobalContext = createContext({});

export const ContextProvider:React.FC<ContextProviderProps> = ({children}) => {
    const ref = useRef< MutableRefObject<HTMLElement>>(null);

 return (
    <GlobalContext.Provider value={ref}>
        {children}
    </GlobalContext.Provider>
 )
}

export const useGlobalContext = () => useContext(GlobalContext);
```

And then i wrap my Layout -

```
export default function RootLayout({children}: LayoutProps) {
 
  return (
    <html className={`h-screen snap-y snap-mandatory scroll-smooth overflow-y-auto hide-scrollbar ${inter.className}`} lang="ru">
      <body className='text-lg px-3 py-6 max-w-7xl mx-auto my-0 bg-[#000] text-[#f2d6d6]'>
        <ContextProvider>
          {children}
        </ContextProvider>
      </body>
    </html>
  )
}
```

[image]
Im new in 13 version, i also tryed to use 'uce client' in the page and didnt work.
Please Help!

Comment: Hi, I have the exact same issue, even if they tell to do like this in the dow it doesn't work. Could you make it work?